# Доступ к элементам массива на языке Java

Tags: java, массивы

Пытаюсь сделать обратный массив, но почему-то не могу получить доступ к элементам в цикле *while*.

```
import  java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindromes {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input;
        input=read.nextInt();
        int []ar={5,6,7,8,9,10};

        for(int i=0; i<=input;i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s",ar[i]);
        }

        int size = ar.length;
        while((size-1)<=0)
        {
            ar.element(5);

            size--;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Доступ к элементам массива имеет такой синтаксис:

```
ИМЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННО_ХРАНЯЩЕЙ_МАССИВ[ИНДЕКС_ЭЛЕМЕНТА];
```

Т.е. в вашем случае:

```
//вместо ar.element(5); надо 
ar[5]
```

Также, думаю, вам надо не фиксированный индекс брать, а последний, т.е.

```
int size = ar.length;
//здесь у вас вообще "меньше или ноль" условие стояло.
    while((size-1)>=0)
    {
        ar[size-1];

        size--;
    }
```

Comment: прям очень, очень интересно, а зачем "size-1"? И чем "while" занимается?

Comment: @barmaglott Я попытался модифицировать код автора, предположив, что он хочет пройтись по массивы с последнего элемента до первого. Я бы, конечно, сделал бы это иначе.

Comment: да я не против (боже упаси ;)) , просто зачем три раза одно и тоже считать?..

Comment: А почему 3? В вопросе, вроде, всего два раза по массиву пытаются пробежаться...

Comment: size-1 в вашем примере 3 раза встречается :)

Comment: @barmaglott, 1 - вычисляется для проверки условия. 2 - для получения последнего элемента массива вычисляется. 3 - уменьшается на 1 и присваивается переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Почему именно while? Задание же легко делается в одном for-цикле

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindromes {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = read.nextInt();
        int [] ar = {5,6,7,8,9,10};

        int ar_len = ar.length;

        // Делаем проход по массиву в обратном порядке
        // начиная от последнего элемента
        for (int i=ar_len-1; i != 0; --i)
            System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Но если Вам просто необходимо юзать именно while, советую глянуть на условие в while'е (там должно быть 'не равно нулю'). И правильно указывайте доступ к элементу массива:

```
ar.element(5); // такого нет в java, если это int array
```

Опять же, нужно указывать индекс, т.е. переменную (в Вашем случае `size`).

Answer (score 0):

Можно взять http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html

тогда

```
int[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
ArrayUtils.reverse(intArray);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```